# Integrate Grunt in docker-compose?

Tags: php, docker, gruntjs, docker-compose

I have two docker compose files that I start with `docker-compose f- docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-osx.yml up`

The file contents is:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    fpm:
        image: sbusso/php-fpm-ion
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
            - fpm
            - db
    db:
        image: orchardup/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: myproject
```

and

docker-compose-osx.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    fpm:
        links:
            - sync
        volumes_from:
            - sync
    db:
        links:
            - sync
        volumes_from:
            - sync
    nginx:
        links:
            - sync
        volumes_from:
            - sync
    sync:
        image: zeroboh/lsyncd
        volumes:
            - /var/www/html
            - ./src:/src:Z
            - ./docker-config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - /var/lib/php/session
            - ./docker-config/lrsync/lrsync.lua:/etc/lrsync/lrsync.lua
            - ./sync:/sync
```

Usually when I connect to my fpm container I need to run grunt, but grunt and npm are not known to my docker container.

How can I integrate grunt here in my docker-compose files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You fpm container (*sbusso/php-fpm-ion*) doesn't have grunt and npm installed (neither its base image). You can see that by reading the Dockerfile [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/sbusso/php-fpm-ion/~/dockerfile/).

*sbusso/php-fpm-ion* is based on *sbusso/php-fpm* which is based on *debian:jessie*. You can install npm and grunt as if you were on any Debian system. The npm version available in debian packages is quite old, you should see their installation guide [on the website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) and then install grunt with `npm install -g grunt-cli`

Keep in mind that containers are isolated from the host, they cannot share neither file nor binaries. Even if you have npm and grunt installed on your host, your container cannot launch them.